# MPMoviePlayerViewController in detailsView in UISplitView fails resize when fullscreen and rotating

Tags: ios, ipad, fullscreen, uisplitviewcontroller

I found a bug on iPad.
let's start a simple application iPAD UISplitView which play a video in the detailView.

If the MPMoviePlayerViewController switch to fullscreen, then rotating the screen, then exit fullscreen : the views are not well arranged (they should be, automatically !) PLUS the statusbar is not more well placed...

Do you have a trick for this buggy behavior ?

Thanks a lot.
Stephane